# Change font’s em size via FontForge Python bindings

Tags: python, fonts, fontforge

I have a small Python script to change fonts via FontForge:

```
import fontforge

font = fontforge.open('font.ttf')
font.em = 1000
font.generate('font.svg')
font.close()
```

The crucial point is

```
font.em = 1000
```

(I need the em size of several fonts normalized before further processing.)

When I do this in FontForge via the GUI, the font is converted just fine: Opening, setting `em` size to `1000` (this step takes FontForge a bit of time usually), exporting as SVG. The resulting font is as expected.

However, doing this via above script ends in mixed-up results, some glyphs not scaled, some with displaced accents, and so on.

What might be the problem with the script? Is there anything to be done so that FontForge scales the `em` size of the font correctly prior to exporting?

Answer (score 0):

EM size is Ascent + Descent.

Do not set with a direct value

```
font.ascent = 860
font.descent = 140
font.em = font.ascent + font.descent
```